# R: webscraping returns no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"?

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr

I'm using RSelenium and purrr functions to generate a df with all the products in this page and their prices:

https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/tv-y-audio/televisores

I'm getting this error, why?

```
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
```

**Code:**

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)


#start RSelenium


rD  <- rsDriver(port = 4560L, browser = "chrome", version = "3.141.59", chromever = "93.0.4577.63",
                geckover = "latest", iedrver = NULL, phantomver = "2.1.1",
                verbose = TRUE, check = TRUE)



remDr <- rD[["client"]]


Sys.sleep(10)

tvs_url <- "https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/tv-y-audio/televisores"

remDr$navigate(tvs_url)

Sys.sleep(10)

#scroll down 20 times, waiting for the page to load at each time
for(i in 1:20){      
  remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");"))
  Sys.sleep(5)    
}


h<-remDr$getPageSource()



df <- map_dfr(h %>%
                map(~ .x %>%
                      html_nodes("div.product")), ~
                data.frame(
                  periodo = lubridate::year(Sys.Date()),
                  fecha = Sys.Date(),
                  ecommerce = "lacuracao",
                  producto = .x %>% html_node(".product_name") %>% html_text(),
                  precio.antes = .x %>% html_node('.old-price') %>% html_text(),
                  precio.actual = .x %>% html_node('#offerPriceValue') %>% html_text()
                ))
```

**Update 1:**

I've changed `h<-remDr$getPageSource()` to `h<-remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]` and now `class(h)` returns character.

[image]

**Update 2:**

Tried:

```
h<-remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

hh <- h %>% read_html() %>% html_elements("div.product")

class(hh) #[1] "xml_nodeset"
```

But getting this when trying to form the df:

```
Error in data.frame(periodo = lubridate::year(Sys.Date()), fecha = Sys.Date(),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

[image]

Comment: What does `class(h)` return? I suspect you need to pipe that into `read_html` before trying to use rvest method calls. Also, is it that you need `remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]` for the actual document to then parse and select with `%>% read_html() %>%html_elements("div.product")` ? Basically, you need an html document object to then parse rather than the page source.

Comment: @QHarr please, see update 1. How do I get the document object? I did: `h<-remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]` and then `h <- h %>% read_html()`. `class(h)` returns `[1] "xml_document" "xml_node"`

Comment: You have now fixed the original problem and you are hitting the issue of the missing child nodes, in some cases, inside of `data.frame` I would imagine. You need to write the logic to handle this. Did my answer to your other question not now solve this problem and return the data you need (at least in terms of approach)?

Comment: Yes, I got it working. You are so kind, QHarr. Ty for your help.

Comment: Is there a way I can contact you, for a freelance work in the future?

Comment: I am frequently on here if you have future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]` to get the actual document.

You then need to pipe that to your DOM parser i.e. `remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html()` and continue on as before i.e. `...%>% html_elements(.....)`.

RSelenium has its own methods for selecting elements via the Webdriver instance e.g. `remDr$findElement("css", "body")`. In your case, you are choosing to transfer the html across into something which you can call rvest's `html_nodes()` on i.e.
[either a document, a node set or a single node.](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/reference/html_element.html). As the transfer is html, then `read_html()` is needed to generate a document for parsing.

The error inside the attempt to form a `data.frame` call is because you need to implement handling of missing child nodes i.e. where certain prices are missing.