# R: webscraping data elements returns NA

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, purrr

I get N/As for the prices. I thought I was ussing the `html_attr()` function correctly, but apparently I'm missing something.

I get the marca and product fields, but not the prices from this HTML:

```
<li data-internet-price="2,899" class="jsx-3342506598 price-0">    
  <div data-variant="DESKTOP_LIST" class="jsx-3342506598 cmr-icon-container"> 
    <span id="" class="copy10 primary high jsx-2612542277 normal     ">
S/  2,899 (Oferta) </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

I would need to capture the content of **data-internet-price**

**CODE:**

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)

urls <- list("https://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat210477/TV-Televisores?page=1",
             "https://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat210477/TV-Televisores?page=2")

h <- urls %>% map(read_html) # scrape once, parse as necessary




df <- map_dfr(h %>%
                map(~ .x %>%
                      html_nodes("div.search-results-list")), ~
                data.frame(
                  periodo = lubridate::year(Sys.Date()),
                  fecha = Sys.Date(),
                  ecommerce = "falabella",
                  marca = .x %>% html_node(".pod-title") %>% html_text(),
                  producto = .x %>% html_node(".pod-subTitle") %>% html_text(),
                  precio.antes = .x %>% html_node('.prices') %>% html_attr("data-internet-price"),
                  precio.actual = .x %>% html_node('.prices') %>% html_attr("data-normal-price")
                ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the html on the page associated with the html as shown above, those attributes do not exist for the nodes you are selecting, hence the N/A i.e. you are actually selecting for parent nodes which don't have the attributes you then try to extract. `html_attr()` works at the level of the current node you pipe from the left hand side.

You want to go further down the DOM, either by adding in a descendant combinator and another selector to your existing `.prices` class css selector e.g. `.prices [data-internet-price]`, or simply directly select the child node with those attributes:

```
precio.antes = .x %>% html_node('[data-internet-price]') %>% html_attr("data-internet-price"),
precio.actual = .x %>% html_node('[data-normal-price]') %>% html_attr("data-normal-price")
```

---

**EDIT:**

Looks like, to get all listings, you need to target a `script` tag, where JavaScript running in browser pulls the additional (>12 per page) listings. You can then parse the JavaScript object retrieved as JSON, and write some custom code to pull out the items you want; whilst handling missing values (which I do by a right join on a default DataFrame housing NA for each of the possible prices).

You may wish to do a final column rename. I have left all 4  price columns in with the names they are given in the page source.

---

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)

urls <- list(
  "https://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat210477/TV-Televisores?page=1",
  "https://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat210477/TV-Televisores?page=2"
)

h <- urls |> map(read_html) # scrape once, parse as necessary

default_df <- data.frame(type = c("cmrPrice", "internetPrice", "normalPrice", "eventPrice"), price = c(NA, NA, NA, NA))

df <- map_dfr(h |>
  map(~ .x |>
    html_node("#__NEXT_DATA__") |>
    html_text() |>
    jsonlite::parse_json() %>%
    {
      .$props$pageProps$results
    }) |> unlist(recursive = F), ~

data.frame(
  periodo = lubridate::year(Sys.Date()),
  fecha = Sys.Date(),
  ecommerce = "falabella",
  marca = .x$brand,
  producto = .x$displayName,
  temp = .x$prices |> map_dfr(~ data.frame(type = .x$type, price = .x$price[[1]])) |>
    right_join(default_df, by = "type", suffix = c("", ".y")) |> select(type, price) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = price)
)) |>
  select_all(~ str_replace(., "temp.", ""))
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you, do you get 96 elements for those 2 pages with my code? I only get 24. But manually counting I see each page has 48 elements.

Comment: Without JS running in browser, as with rvest, there are 12 listings for page 1 returned for that selector in the html.

Comment: I think I need to use RSelenium. I got this other question where I got stucked with it, may you check it, pls? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69186034/r-webscrapping-returns-no-applicable-method-for-xml-find-all-applied-to-an-ob

Comment: You don't need to do that. You just need to extract from script tag. I will update answer.

Comment: Ty. What captures my attention is that you use what I call an attribute as a node: `html_node('[data-internet-price]')`  , for me the node would be the `<li>`.   What is a node then? couldn't find enough info in rvest pckg info page.  

Also, please, see my other question that uses RSelenium.

Comment: Are you familiar with [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)? You can absolutely use attributes e.g. attribute selectors. `li` would be a `type` selector. Also, see [node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node). You could instead think of html elements and those elements having attributes.